# Windows Authentication in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a .NET application (mix of C# and VB.NET) where I would like to display a Windows Login Dialog box (or my own dialog box) and authenticate the user using Windows Authentication. Per requirement, I need to ask the user to authenticate after AT LEAST a minute of being idle. I would prefer a .NET native way of doing Windows Authentication but interested in other ways...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to authenticate a user, you can use the [ValidateCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300969.aspx) method of the [PrincipalContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351875.aspx). Make sure to add reference `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

```
//If you are validating on a domain
PrincipalContext pcon = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);    
if(pcon.ValidateCredential(txtUsername.Text, 
                           txtPassword.Text, 
                           ContextOptions.Negotiate))
{
    //User is authenticated
}
```

If you're not validating against a domain, check other `ContextType`. You can also use other option to validate the credentials (the `ContextOptions`).

Comment: Although this sounds like the best way to do it - just found out these classes are not available to .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Found the following and figured I'd add it for completion sake. I still like Gabriel's answer!

```
Private Declare Auto Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal lpszUsername As String, ByVal lpszDomain As String, ByVal lpszPassword As String, ByVal dwLogonType As LogonType, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Integer
Private Declare Auto Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As Boolean

    Public Enum LogonType As Integer
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2
        LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3
        LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4
        LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5
        LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7
        LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8
        LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9
    End Enum

    Public Function IsAuthenticated(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String, Optional ByVal Domain As String = "") As Boolean
        Dim Token As New IntPtr
        LogonUser(Username, Domain, Password, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, 0, Token)
        CloseHandle(Token)
        If Token.ToInt32 <> 0 Then Return True
    End Function
```

Comment: Why would you use unmanaged code when you can do everything with managed code?

Comment: Because the managed code is not available in .NET framework 2.0